# Android studio how to take the data from SQLlite and put it on EditText

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, listview

I'm a beginner at coding and i really hope you can help me.
So my problem is that i made a SQLite Database and i saved the information from edit text into a ListView but now i want that when ill click on a specific item on the list it will open the EditList activity with all the information that the user typed and saved there before please help me, this is my code(i already checked that all the information is saved i just wanna know to edit it when clicking on item on a list):

This is my Database helper:

```
 package com.example.lian.atlist;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by Lian on 18-Sep-18.
 */

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "List.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Notes_table";
    public static final String ID = "ID";
    public static final String TITLE = "TITLE";
    public static final String DESCRIPTION = "DESCRIPTION";

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    //    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,TITLE TEXT,DESCRIPTION TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String title,String description){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues= new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(TITLE,title);
        contentValues.put(DESCRIPTION,description);
        long result =db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        if(result==-1){
            return false;
        }else
        return true;
    }
    public Cursor getAllData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " +TABLE_NAME,null);
        return  res;
    }
    public boolean updateData(String id,String title,String description){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues= new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(ID,id);
        contentValues.put(TITLE,title);
        contentValues.put(DESCRIPTION,description);
        db.update(TABLE_NAME,contentValues,"ID = ?",new String[]{id});
        return true;
    }
}
```

this is my Main Activity:

```
package com.example.lian.atlist;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Debug;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.EventLogTags;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static com.example.lian.atlist.EditList.Description;
import static com.example.lian.atlist.EditList.Title;
import static com.example.lian.atlist.EditList.id;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DataBaseHelper myDB;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

        myDB= new DataBaseHelper(this);
        ListView listView =(ListView)  findViewById(R.id.LV);
        ArrayList<String> TheList = new ArrayList<>();
        final Cursor data =myDB.getAllData();
        ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,TheList);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

       listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

          Intent EditNote = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditList.class);
         startActivity(EditNote);
                                           }
       });

        if (data.getCount()==0){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The list is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            while(data.moveToNext()){
                TheList.add(data.getString(1));


            }
        }

        Intent SaveNote = getIntent();

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

               Intent addNote = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditList.class);
               startActivity(addNote);
            }
        });
    }




}
```

This is my EditList Activity:

```
package com.example.lian.atlist;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.security.PublicKey;

public class EditList extends AppCompatActivity {
    static TextView id;
    static EditText Title;
    static EditText Description;
    Button SaveButton;
    DataBaseHelper myDB;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_list);
        myDB = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        id=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.id);
        Title=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Description=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        SaveButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.SaveButton);
        AddData();
        viewAll();
        UpdateData();

    }
    Intent AddNote = getIntent();
    Intent EditNote = getIntent();



    public void UpdateData(){
        boolean isUpdated = myDB.updateData(id.getText().toString()
                ,Title.getText().toString()
                ,Description.getText().toString());
        if (isUpdated==true){
                Toast.makeText(EditList.this,"Data Updated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(EditList.this, "Data is not Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }



    public void viewAll(){
        Cursor res = myDB.getAllData();
        if(res.getCount()==0){
            //show message
            showMessage("Error","Nothing found");
            return;
        }
    }

    public void showMessage(String title,String Message){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(Message);
        builder.show();
    }
        public void AddData(){
        SaveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

               boolean isInserted= myDB.insertData(Title.getText().toString()
                        ,Description.getText().toString());


                if (isInserted == true){
                    Toast.makeText(EditList.this,"Data Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(EditList.this, "Data is not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                Intent SaveNote = new Intent(EditList.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(SaveNote);
            }
        });
        }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. One of them is to pass the id of the element that you clicked using extras

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, EditActivity.class);
i.putExtra("id", id); //Find id using the position in the click listener
startActivity(i);
```

Then in EditActivity do

```
Intent i= getIntent();
int id = i.getIntExtra("id", 0);
```

Once you get the id, just do your database query and show the details.

Comment: can u show me an example of how to do query and show details? and where do i put it oncreate?

Comment: i wrote this(it didnt work):
    public void UpdateData(){
        boolean isUpdated = myDB.updateData(id.getText().toString()
                ,Title.getText().toString()
                ,Description.getText().toString());
        Intent i= getIntent();
        int idd = i.getIntExtra("id", 0);
        id.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("id"));
        id.setText(myDB.ID.toString());
        Title.setText(myDB.TITLE.toString());
        Description.setText(myDB.DESCRIPTION.toString());